# Problema al convertir .TIFF a PDF con PYTHON

Tags: python, imagen, pdf, tiff

cuando uso el siguiente código:

```
 from PIL import Image
image = Image.open('in.tif')
image.save("out.pdf", save_all=True)
```

sobre una imágen en formato .tiff

y trato de abrir el archivo resultante .pdf con adobe me aparece el siguiente error:
 Las dimensiones de esta pagina superan los limites. es posible que se corte el contenido de la página.
 y no me abre el archivo.

Pueden ayudarme.

Gracias

Comment: Yo te recomendaría NO subir imágenes de archivos y menos de este tipo donde se ven firmas y contenido que puede ser de caracter confidencial

Comment: tienes toda la razón, gracias @Aprendiz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

puedes hacerlo asi:

```
from PIL import Image
def convert_(imagen):
    # obtenemos el nombre del archivo
    outfile = imagen.split(".")[0]
    # abrimos la imagen
    img = Image.open(imagen)
    # convertimos a formato RGB
    out = img.convert("RGB")
    # guardamos la imagen
    out.save(outfile+".pdf","PDF", quality=90)

## llamamos a la funcion
convert_('img.TIF')
```

Comment: Gracias Bryro, con este código se arregla el problema, me puedes explciar que hacemos?

Comment: @AndresMarin no te entiendo andres hacemos?? en que ??

Comment: me puedes explicar por qué mi código no funcionaba? solo por la conversión a rgb?

Comment: es porque `pdf` es un formato para documentos. mientras que  `tiff` es un formato de imagenes sin compresion por ende tendra una nitides de color en bruto [raw](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raw_(formato)) asi que requieres convertir esos colores a un formato mas standar como lo es `rgb` en pocas palabras es como intentar mostrar una pelicula 8k en un televisor blanco y negro!

Comment: Perfecto, Gracias Brother!

Answer (score 1):

Andres, te comento que yo no pude reproducir el problema, pero de todos modos te propongo redimensionar la imagen antes de generar el pdf.

Con `size`, que es una tupla, puedes obtener las dimensiones de la imagen. Usé una división por 2 para obtener la mitad de cada medida, y luego dejé ese valor como entero `int(imagen.size[0]/2)`.

Finalmente `resize` permite cambiar el tamaño de la imagen, para luego guardarla del modo en que hiciste originalmente.

```
from PIL import Image
imagen = Image.open('la_imagen.jpg')
mitad = (int(imagen.size[0]/2), int(imagen.size[1]/2))
imagen_redimensionada = imagen.resize(mitad)

imagen_redimensionada.save("out.pdf", save_all=True)
```

Comment: Gracias Rodrigo pero sigue saliendo el mismo error.